# Creating two Numpy arrays in Pandas DataFrame Cells and performing multiplication between them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'col1': [[1,2,3]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Now lets say I want to create two new columns, `squared` and `cubed` like:

```
df['squared'] = [np.array([i**2 for i in x]) for x in df['col1']]
df['cubed'] = [np.array([i**3 for i in x]) for x in df['col1']]

df
        col1   squared      cubed
0  [1, 2, 3] [1, 4, 9] [1, 8, 27]
```

Now I would want to do element-wise multiplication and sum with each element of the `squared` and `cubed` numpy arrays. How could I go about doing this an an efficient manner (if say I had a large amount of data?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try matrix multiplication.

```
df.apply(lambda x: x['squared'] @ x['cubed'], axis=1)
```

Comment: I don't think I've seen ```@``` used in this context. Is this a Pandas or Numpy feature? I really like it.

Comment: It's available in both actually, but most people aren't aware it's been part of Python since I believe 3.5.  But in this case numpy